# TCPListener accepting single TCPClient at one time

Tags: tcpclient, tcplistener

I am implementing a TCPListener server. How can I accept only one TCPClient at one time and block for other TCPClients (queue other attempts)? When the active client closed, then listener accepts the following one from the queue. I need some thread-safe source code.